# batch script for renaming a user account in windows xp or windows 7

Tags: batch-file, rename

Is there any way to change a username/account name using batch scripting? For example, change the username "testing" into "TESTING123", "Testing" or "testing123"? Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's not possible if via BAT/CMD batch script alone. You'll need a JScript/VBScript to do that. And there will be side effects for all installed programs too.

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to do this via wmic:

```
wmic useraccount where name="old_name" call rename "new_name"
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware you can't do this in batch. You can create new accounts and delete old accounts but you can't rename them :)

For all user account stuff in batch type `net user /?` at a cmd prompt, or even just `net /?`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a windows 10 user, this worked for me.

```
wmic useraccount where name="%username%" call rename "myname4"
```

Change "myname4" to fit your use case.

Keep in mind, you should execute the batch as administrator or else this may not work. (It sometimes works, but not always, when not executed as administrator.)